# iOS NSPredicate with nested JSON array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nspredicate

Consider the following JSON object:

```
[
  {
  "name":"joe",
  "place":"here",
  "type":[
     "abc",
     "cde",
     "efg"
     ]
  },
  {
  "name":"ian",
  "place":"somewhere",
  "type":[
     "c",
     "ddd",
     "eee"
     ]
  },
  {
  "name":"mike",
  "place":"there",
  "type":[
     "any",
     "place",
     "nice"
     ]
  },
]
```

How would I create a predicate in Objective-C to query the values of the different "type" objects and filter based on that

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create predicate with block, and within block create your compare function.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings) {
  if([[evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"name"] isEqual:@"SomeString]) {
     return YES;
  } else {
     return NO;
  }
}
```

This simple first level comparing, but you get a point. From this object you can go deeper and return YES/NO at point you can determine compare results.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in an NSArray named jsonArray, you can filter on type with:

```
NSString *typeToSelect = @"abc";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY type like %@",typeToSelect];
NSArray *filteredArray = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```